# Jquery plugin add new click event

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic, plugins, click

I'm trying to make a tag plugin that uses the autocompletion (jquery ui : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). When you click on a value in the dropdown list it creats a span with a cross to remove it.

My question is how could i register in my plugin a click event on the new created span cross sign.

```
/**
 * Tags Autocomplete
 *
 * Create tags through autocompletion
 */
(function($)
{
    'use strict';

    $.fn.tagsAutocomplete = function(options)
    {
        // defaults
        var defaults = {
            autocomplete : {
                source : "",
                test_data: ["test", "testing", "tester", "John DOe"]
            },
            tags : {
                class : "tag"
            }
        };

        // selected element
        var elm = this;

        // extend the options
        var o = $.extend(true, defaults, options);

        // Start autocomplete
        $(elm).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: o.autocomplete.test_data,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                // add tag to DOM, before the input with a remove_tag
                $(this).before('<span class="tag tag-green tag-new">'+ui.item.value+'' +
                    '<span class="remove_tag"></span>' +
                    '</span>');

                // clear input
                this.value = "";

                // return false
                return false;
            }
        });

        /**
         * Remove span after clicking the cross
         * @param obj
         */
        function removeSpan(obj){
            alert('clicks works');
            //obj.closest(o.tags.class).remove();
            // focus input
            //obj.focus();
        }

        // bind events
        this.bind("click.remove_tag", removeSpan);

        // return elm for chaining
        return elm;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried this: this.bind("click.remove_tag", removeSpan);
But that doesn't work.

So how can i add a click event on the new create span with a class name remove_tag

Answer (score 0):

You're using namepaced events, you're not targeting classes.

To target the newly created dynamic span element, you'd do

```
elm.parent().on("click", ".remove_tag", removeSpan);
```

and because the span is inserted before the `elm` element, you have to delegate to the parent element

```
function removeSpan(evt){
    $(evt.target).closest('.remove_tag').focus().closest(o.tags.class).remove();
}
```

Comment: Clicks works, but how can i get the clicked dom element.   
function removeSpan(obj){log($(this).text());} // not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", function() {
  removespan();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have my removeSpan function like this:

```
    /**
     * Remove span after clicking the cross
     */
    function removeSpan(){
        // remove tag
        $(this).closest($(o.tags.class)).remove();
        // focus input
        $(elm).focus();
    }
```

And the clicked span gets removed.

I have another question. but first let me explain how the tags are build.

This is my html

```
<div class="tags_container">
     // jquery add the spans (tags) here before the input placeholder
    <input class="tag_input" name="testFoo" type="text" placeholder=""/>
</div>
```

I look likes this
[image]

As you can see, after the tags there is an input the placeholder. Now i want the option to remove the last span on backspace. I've tried this before. But there is some difficulty.

In the picture when you count the chars on backspace and the "j" will be backspaced the count is 0. When the user now press backspace the last tag must be removed. But the length could not be -1. What is a common way to solve this issue.